# How to get an element from a String Array, if the String array itself is an element of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Let me give you an example;

```
String[] one = {"one", "two"};
String[] two = {"bob", "lol", "hi"};
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
list.add(one);
list.add(two);
```

Now, I want to get the 2nd string array (which is 'two') in list. I do this by:

```
list.get(2);
```

But, say if I wanted to get the 2nd element in the two String array in List ( Basically I want to get the string "lol" from list->two->lol).

Is this how you do it:

```
list.get(2).get(2)
```

Comment: That should be `list.get(1)[1]`, since list indices start at 0, not 1, `list.get(1)` is an array and array indices start at 0, not 1. Arrays don't have a `.get()` method.

Comment: ... and list.get(1)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indices in Java (and in most programming languages) **starts with `0`**, so if you want to access to the second element you must use the index `1`:

```
list.get(0)[1];
```

**Note** that

```
list.get(0)
```

will return the *first* `String[]` array, and to access to an element of an array you have to use the syntax:

```
someArray[index]
```

Comment: @EbadSaghar this answer posted on 06:33:36, 3sec after my answer (06:33:33) :P
but its okay, this is more perfect

Answer (score 0):

Array starts with index 0. so you have to use list.get(i)[1]